# In C++, how to print ASCII art to the console?

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, ascii-art

Let's say you want to print out one of those great ASCII art images.  How can you do that without `cout` each line individually?

Comment: Since C++11 you can use the raw string literal. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34737663/1749675 for an example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adjacent string literals are concatenated, so you can do this:

```
cout << " _______________________ _______ _          _______         _______ _______  _______ _       _______         \n"
        "(  ____ \__   __/  ___  )  ____ \ \    /\  (  ___  )\     /|  ____ \  ____ )(  ____ \ \     (  ___  )\     /|\n"
        "| (    \/  ) (  | (   ) | (    \/  \  / /  | (   ) | )   ( | (    \/ (    )|| (    \/ (     | (   ) | )   ( |\n"
        "| (_____   | |  | (___) | |     |  (_/ /   | |   | | |   | | (__   | (____)|| (__   | |     | |   | | | _ | |\n"
        "(_____  )  | |  |  ___  | |     |   _ (    | |   | | (   ) )  __)  |     __)|  __)  | |     | |   | | |( )| |\n"
        "      ) |  | |  | (   ) | |     |  ( \ \   | |   | |\ \_/ /| (     | (\ (   | (     | |     | |   | | || || |\n"
        "/\____) |  | |  | )   ( | (____/\  /  \ \  | (___) | \   / | (____/\ ) \ \__| )     | (____/\ (___) | () () |\n"
        "\_______)  )_(  |/     \|_______/_/    \/  (_______)  \_/  (_______//   \__/|/      (_______/_______)_______)\n";
```

Or, more accurately, perhaps:

````````````````````
cout << "                              .::/-                                                                                                                                                             \n"
        "                              .+++/                                                                                                                                                             \n"
        "                   `.::`       /+++.                                                                                                                                                            \n"
        "                  -////.      :+++-                                                                                                                                                             \n"
        "                    .////-`    .+++/`                                                                                                                                                           \n"
        "                    `:///:`   `/++/.                                                                                                                                                            \n"
        "            ..`        -////.   -+++:                                                                                                                                                           \n"
        "           :+++:-`      .////:` ./++/`                                                                                                                                                          \n"
        "          `-/+++++/-.    `:////.`:++/.                                                                                                                                                          \n"
        "             `.:/++++/:.`  -////..:--`                                                                                                                                                          \n"
        "                 .-/+++++/-..::.`                                                                                                                                                               \n"
        "       `:::-..``    `.:/++++-                                                                                                                                                                   \n"
        "       -++++++///:--.```.-/-                                                                                                                                                                    \n"
        "        `.--:///++++++//::.                                                                                                                                                                     \n"
        "`--.          ``..-::///+/``---                                                 -+-                                                             ./oso- /++:                                     \n"
        "-oo+  -::::----....````... `ooo                  :s-                            /mo                                                            -dmmhy:`hmmo                                     \n"
        "-oo+  /+++++++++++++++++/. `ooo                  om:                            /mo             ````     ```      ```    ``.``      ```  `.``  ommd`` `hmmo       ``.``    ```     ```     ```  \n"
        "-oo+  ...----::::////+++/` `ooo      `/ssyss+:`.ohmyoo` .+ssyss+-     -+syys+-  /mo    -o+.  .ohdmmdho- -hdd/   `sdds` :shmmmdy/`  .hddshdmmhoydmmmhy:`hmmo    .+hdmmmds- .ddd/   .ddh-   +ddh. \n"
        "-oo+  ```````````````````  `ooo     .yh-.``-/-  .sm/.` `/o-```-sd+  .sd+-..-++` /mo  .odo.  :dmmy+/smmm: +mmh-  /mmd- +mmh+:/smmy- .dmmdo/+s:`/ymmm++.`hmmo   .dmmh++smmd+`ommd` `ymmmy  .hmm+  \n"
        "-oo+  +oooooooooooooooooo- `ooo     -dy.         om:           -dy` +m/         /mo`+dy-   `smmy`  `smmy``smms`.hmm/ -dmd+---:hmmo`.dmm+       ommd   `hmmo   ommh.   ommh..ymm+ +mmdmm/ ommy.  \n"
        "-oo+  /++++++++++++++++++. `ooo      -oyhyyys/`  om:   `:osyyyyymy``sm-         /myhyhd:   `smms    +mmh` `dmm/smms  :dmmddddddddo`.dmm/       ommd   `hmmo   smmy`   /mmd. :dmd+dmy-ymd+hmd:   \n"
        "-oo+                       `ooo          ``.+do  om:   /do.    -dy``om:         /md/``od+` `ommh.  `ymmy`  :dmmmmy.  .hmd/`````.`  .dmm/       ommd    hmmo   +mmh-   smmy` `smmmmm- :dmmmmo    \n"
        "-oo+:::::::::::::::::::::::/ooo     -+:.```.od+  +mo.` /do.```.omy` .sd/.``.//` /mo    +dy. -ymmdysdmmh-    +mmmh-    :dmmyoosdd+` .dmm/       ommd    ommmso.`ymmdyshmmh:   .hmmm+   +mmmd`    \n"
        "-oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo     ./syyyyyo:`  `:sys.`:syyyys+yo`  `:syyyyo:` :h/     :ys` `:shddhs/`     `ohy/      ./shddhy+-  .shh:       /hhy    `:syhs. `:oyhdhs/.     /hho`   `shh/     \n"
````````````````````

More sensibly, use `endl`. This is subtly different from just "\n" after each line, because you'll also flush the output stream.

Comment: It's the "Epic" font, from patorjk.com's generator.

Comment: These examples won't work as they are filled with escape sequences. Everywhere you see a "\" is the start of an escape sequence and will not display on the console at all.  Compile it and you'll get warnings about them in fact.  I'm trying to figure out how this got picked as the best answer still.

Comment: The examples give `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\_'` playing with the fonts does not add anything useful to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

try something like:

```
cout << R"(place multiple lines
           of text here
           and it will display exactly
           as you have it between the two brackets,
           line feeds and all.)";
```

...the above code will also allow you to use characters like the backslash \ without needing two of them, it displays everything and doesn't recognize control codes, like \n etc.  Very handy.

This is called a "string literal" and was added in C++11.  You can find more information on the commands here, specifically refer to the prefix "R" which is for raw_characters: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Was this added in a particular version?

Comment: I honestly don't recall.  I used it with Visual Studio a few years ago and it worked fine, so you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Happen to know what version of C++ you were using? I ask with all of the v11 C++ projects out there who possibly couldn't make use of this if it was added in one of the post-2011 versions. As best I can tell it looks like a C11/C99 addition, but cannot verify.

Comment: I done some more searching and I finally found it.  It is called a "string literal" and it was added in C++11.  Here's a page describing more details on what you can use.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @NeilRoy More specifically, it's a 'raw string literal'. Calling it simply a 'string literal' is confusing, because `"foobar"` is also a 'string literal'.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat While calling it that makes it clearer, the name of it in C++11 is simply "string literal".  And there are different types you can do, it is not technically called a "raw string literal" but rather a "string literal" which contain raw_characters.  This may seem like a nit pick on my part, but clicking the link makes this quite clear and there would be no confusion given my example code plus the link.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already suggested using `endl`. While this isn't (necessarily) a bad thing, using `endl` flushes the stream's buffer along with writing a new-line. Contrary to the implication in one of the answers you've gotten, using `endl` does *not* help (at all) with translating the new-line to whatever character sequence the platform normally uses to signal the end of a line. Using `newline` is guaranteed to be precisely equivalent to `stream << "\n" << flush;"`. Translating new-lines to "\r", or "\n" or "\r\n", or whatever the platform prefers, is done at a different level and `newline` has nothing to do with it.

The `flush` that it does, however, can (and often will) slow down your I/O, sometimes by quite a considerable margin. As long as you're only writing a few lines (e.g. a couple hundred characters) it's probably completely irrelevant. If you're writing a large file, however, using `endl` instead of `"\n"` can easily result in a 10x slowdown (in fact, I'd go so far as to say that much of the idea that iostreams are slow stems directly from using `endl`).

That's not to say there's never any reason to use endl. The `flush` assures that whatever has been written to the stream is immediately flushed out of the standard library's buffer, and sent to the OS. If you want to assure immediate display, `endl` can be useful. Likewise, if you're doing logging, and it's critical that your log always reflect the most recent known state of a program, `endl` can be (extremely) useful to assure that what you've written really gets logged, not lost in a buffer when/if the application crashes.

So, `endl` makes sense at times, but probably 95% of the time that it's used, it's really inappropriate (e.g., it's unlikely to accomplish anything useful in any of the answers to this question).

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple thankfully.  Just use endl whenever you want to start another line.

```
cout << stuff << endl
     << morestuff << endl
     << evenmorestuff << endl;
```

I would like to state that I much prefer using endl because it should work even if you are on a platform that requires "\r\n" instead of just "\n".

Comment: While an obvious answer, printing many lines this way may become a burden for the CPU if done frequently. Each use of the overloaded operator << is hiding a function call behind it, so printing multiline text requires MANY function calls.

Comment: Yes it can become a burden done that way but if all he is doing is printing a bit of ascii art, it shouldn't be a problem.  The other way would be to do the work of packing it all into one big string and shoving it all out at once.  I have had to do that on occasion but most of the time, this method isn't a problem.

Comment: Your remark about `std::endl` is silly.  Even if you are on a platform that requires `\r\n` instead of `\n` as its native line terminator, `\n` is still the newline terminator in C and C++, and the I/O libraries convert it for you. (This is the difference between text-mode and binary-mode streams.) `std::endl` is somewhat less efficient than raw `\n` since it unnecessarily flushes the stream.

Comment: You're probably right but I did have problems with it many many years ago.  Next to nothing being used these days has problems with just using '\n'.

Comment: Read the question again.  He specifically asked how to do this without couting each line.